# On Careers, why can't I reference an application that's not web accessible?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I don't know about you but most of my work is classified and not web accessible at all.

Solution anyone ?

Comment: Took me a hot second to figure out you were talking about Careers, minor title edit for clarification.

Comment: You can put any links you like in in the individual employment history bits (I've put both links to public websites and descriptions / documentation for non-public websites in these); is there some special functionality that's only available to links in the Projects section?

Comment: Actually, Aakash, links are still a very dubious approach - I meant to upload a few screenshots like I did on another website - not that I think it's the best approach yet.  THis is mostly about trying to find a solution for all those who do real work that's hidden in a corporate, private or secret network and thus can't simply be accessed through a link

Comment: Um, ok, but you can put any *text* you like in the employment history bits too. Is there some special functionality that's only available to links in the Projects section?